# jQuery Propagation Firefox Bug?

Tags: jquery, firefox

This script is working perfectly with Chrome and Safari, but Firefox is bugging up for some reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

    $j(function(){
        $j('.next').click(function() {
            location.href = $j(this).attr('href');
        });
        $j('.prev').click(function(){
            location.href = $j(this).attr('href');
        });

    });

    $j('body').keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==82) {
            $j(document).trigger(location.href = '/?random');
        }
        if(event.keyCode==39) {
            $j('.next').trigger('click');
        }
        if(event.keyCode==37) {
            $j('.prev').trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $j('input, textarea').keydown(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});
</script>
```

If you press left or right on your keyboard, it takes you to the next/prev page. If you hit R, it takes you to a random page. HOWEVER, if you are typing something in an `input` or `textarea`, the keyboard navigation is turned off (so the you can type without an unexpected page load if you hit R, left, or right).

It works great in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox it bugs and the keyboard nav instead ONLY works if you're typing in an `input` or `textarea`. It does the opposite of what is intended.

I've disabled all add-ons in Firefox which didn't help. There have been a couple random times when it has worked properly, but I can't replicate them. I'm stumped as to why this isn't working in Firefox... any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `event` parameter in your function:

```
$j('input, textarea').keydown(function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Durr, I feel dumb. Thanks for the help! Also, I had to change `$j('body').keydown(function(event)` to `$j(document).keydown(function(event)`. body works for Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

Comment: No problem. Others always find your bugs better than you ever could (same applies to me) :P